# Appium with Android Enterprise (Work-Profile)

Tags: android, adb, appium

I'm not able to start the app with Appium in Work-Profile.

The adb-Tool has a launcher flag "--user", but Appium has no equivalent Capabilities-Flag. I found following Release-Note: https://discuss.appium.io/t/appium-1-8-1-release/22162

There should be the Flag "userProfile" but its not working for me.

Is there any other solution to launch the app with appium in another user-profile? Or start the app with adb and use the running instance for the tests?

Comment: "but its not working for me" in my opinion its not enough to get what you mean. Elaborate your issue please, provide some exceptions etc.

Comment: Ok. I mean: Appium ignores the flag "userProfile"..

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was able to accomplish this with Appium Desktop  by adding another parameter to the inspector:

optionalIntentArguments text --user 12

Where '12' is the work profile id you'd see from typing this:
adb -d shell pm list users
Users:
    UserInfo{0:Ken Corey:13} running
    UserInfo{12:Workspace:50100030} running

Comment: How does the command works? Where to set it? Under desired capabilities? optionalIntentArguments text --user 12